# Starting more the 4 android emulator/virtual machines on Mac

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation, haxm

Whenever I try to run more then 4 android VMs I get this message

```
emulator: Failed to create vm ffffffff

emulator: Failed to create HAX VM
```

HAX is the [Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager).

Does anyone know how to run more the 4 VMs?

Comment: maybe you are out of memory!

Comment: @MoshErsan I had this problem previously and I got some kind of _out of memory_ message. I increased it with the intel HAXM installer and everything was fine. The _Failed to create HAX VM_ message come later as I tried to start the fifth VM.

Comment: I mean you are out of memory (RAM)

Comment: @MoshErsan I guess you are right, it is probably the RAM. I get a message for everything on my Mac but this time nothing. I will test it on a machine with more RAM and we will see if it worked.

Comment: what happened at the end? @gravmatt

Comment: @AlejandroLora I had a older version of adb installed. Witch seamed the cause of the problem so fare I remember. I updated it and I was able to run more then just 4 VMs. But keep an eye on the memory. they use a lot and it could also be a reason.